# gnome-screenshot doesn't autosave but interactively asks for a save directory

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, screenshot

I've specified an `auto-save-directory` in `dconf-editor` under `org.gnome.gnome-screenshot` however it still asks me for a save directory every time I take a screenshot.

---

In prior Linux Mint versions (17, 17.3, ...) it went like this: I press <kbd>Print</kbd>, the screen goes white, and then I continue doing what I was doing (with a screenshot being made and put into the auto-save-directory)

In 18 however a dialog pops up after it goes white and asks me interactively what I want to name the screenshot and what folder I want to put it in.

I find this very annoying since I put them all in the same folder and don't bother with filenames since the current date and time are usually descriptive enough (plus they're chronologically sorted). Can I change the behavior of `gnome-screenshot` or are there any alternative programs?

Comment: I started using `scrot` as Custom Shortcut using the `Print` key however if I want to screenshot only the current *window* (`Alt`+`Print`) this still invokes `gnome-screenshot` and that annoying dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround (tldr: delete default shortcuts and replace them with shortcuts that call scripts which activate gnome-screenshots and set the desired save path). See https://cialu.net/how-to-change-default-gnome-screenshot-savings-folder/ for complete instructions.

*edit to add more detail:
Per instructions given at the link above, referencing this bug https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642, this issue is not going to change. Here's how to work around it in case the link breaks in future.

1) Go to Keyboard Settings > Shortcuts > Screenshots. You'll see some shortcuts already assigned; the top three should be to save a full screenshot, save a screenshot of a window, and save a screenshot of an area.

2) Disable the default shortcut keys (by default PrintScreen Alt+PrintScreen and Shift+PrintScreen) for these commands by selecting the shortcut and pressing the Backspace key.

3)Now select the Custom Shortcuts menu, and make three new shortcuts for the same behaviors (save complete screenshot, one of just one window, or one of just the selected area). For the command for each shortcut type the command sh -c, followed by the path to the executable script you want to fire for that command.

example: `sh -c '/home/user/.scripts/screenshot-full.sh'`

would be my command to take a full screenshot

4)In the directory where you keep your executable shell scripts, (~/.scripts in the example) write scripts to perform each desired behavior.

examples:

#### full screen capture

`#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%F-%T)
gnome-screenshot -f /home/user/screenshot_directory/Screenshot-$DATE.png`

#### window capture

`#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)
gnome-screenshot -w -f /home/user/screenshot_directory/Screenshot-$DATE.png`

#### area capture

`#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)
gnome-screenshot -a -f 
/home/user/screenshot_directory/Screenshot-$DATE.png`

5) Make each script executable by running the chmod command.
examples:

`sudo chmod a+x '/home/user/.scripts/screenshot-full.sh'`

`sudo chmod a+x '/home/user/.scripts/screenshot-window.sh'`

`sudo chmod a+x '/home/user/.scripts/screenshot-area.sh'`

That's all there is to it. Now when you press the shortcut keys, the script will execute and the screenshots taken will be automatically saved to your chosen screenshot_directory.

(If your shell fu is strong, you can also do the same thing with a single script by having the shortcuts pass options to it. Developing this more elegant version is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  People should be able to follow the steps by reading your answer — the page you linked to might go away.   (Leave the link in your post, to give credit to the source of the information.)

Comment: @scott, yes I can, and did. Thanks for the pull up. I hate it myself when I find what looks like the solution to my problem only to discover the link is broken and the answer doesn't give enough detail for me to duplicate the fix.

Comment: Great answer, I had trouble setting the shortcut to 'Alt + Print', the trick is to hold 'Print' first and then press 'Alt'. Otherwise you will just get 'Alt L' or 'Alt R'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `scrot` . Detailed post on how to set it up with shortcut key and saving to a specific folder here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1238869/730518

Comment: I also use scrot for the Print key now, but is there any way to use Alt+Print for capturing a specific window instead of the whole screen? gnome-screenshot has that feature and I need it.

Comment: So at my end Linux Mnt has its own application that does it with a window popping up. I've moved it from PrnScr to Ctrl+PrnScr. Don't know about gnome-screenshot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that application is gnome-screenshot